# HTML+CSS to png image

Tags: php, html, image

I need to create PNG image from HTML which include images and heavy css.

Comment: Thanks for sharing. I need you to read [How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Providing details will help people to understand the question and get you  the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [html2canvas](http://html2canvas.hertzen.com/javascript%20library). This library let you to save an html element with css to a `canvas`. After you do so, you can save the canvas to an image.

Check this out:

```js
document.querySelector('#screenshot').onclick = function() {
  html2canvas(document.querySelector('#board'), {
    onrendered: function(canvas) {
        document.body.appendChild(canvas);
    }
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/html2canvas/0.4.1/html2canvas.min.js"></script>

<div id="board">
  <p>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Default</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Primary</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-success">Success</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-info">Info</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning">Warning</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">Danger</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-link">Link</button>
  </p>
</div>

<hr />

<button id="screenshot" type="button" class="btn btn-default">Take a picture</button>

<hr />
```